# SQL Server Transactional Replication - Error number: 213 - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, subscription, transactional-replication

I have an issue with Transactional Replication which I am struggling to resolve.

This is the error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. (Source: SQL Server, Error number: 213)

The error is occurring on an `INSERT` statement when the article is getting delivered to the subscriber. The error seems to be occurring for all the float columns

> insert into [dbo].[Table] (
> [id],[Client_No],[Loan_No],[Client_Name],[Loan_Amt],[Loan_Balance],[Loan_Int_Paid],[Loan_lsinst],[PartAmt],[InstNoPaid],[CentreId],[GroupId],[Loan_Dt],[finChrg],[Loan_Stat],[FirstInstDt],[Loan_Int],[Loan_Prd],[Loan_DueDt],[Loan_Inst],[Loan_Typ],[IRR],[FlatRate],[ROCode],[ROCodeOrg],[Loan_pen],[Loan_penpaid],[loan_Oc],[Loan_Ocpaid],[Loan_legal],[WOff],[WOffDt],[Reschedule],[Loan_Suggest],[Loan_Leg_Rem],[loan_woff_rem],[loan_sector],[loan_use],[Loan_ClDt],[Brn_Code],[Remarks],[I
> nsureAmt],[ProcessFee],[sTax],[trn_autNo],[LastPaidOn],[Loan_Cat],[Cycle],[invoiceNo],[BuyOutDt],[BuyOutBnk],[BuyOutFlg],[ResponseDt],[EndLoanUtil],[Util_Empno],[InsurComp],[CoolDys],[Collday],[CollWeek],[NetDisbFlg],[ML_ClAmt],[LastPaidAmt],[WoffBO],[WoffBODt],[LastEMI],[DisbBank],[NextDueDt],[ArrearNos],[DisbTyp],[GL_Fdgl],[GAN],[Bank_Id],[Nominee_Id],[IsAndroid],[Created_On],[Created_By],[Updated_On],[Updated_By],[Doc_Download],[Lot_Time],[CollMode],[Ref_LoanNo],[Sanction_dt],[GenInsu],[NatCatInsr],[Mast
> erLoanUtil],[NachStatus],[NatCatInsrFlg],[SoftCopyStatus],[PennyDrop],[EximId],[Mort_Int],[InterestPaidUpto],[MortInsAmt])
> values ( 6494935,1002460000002934,1102460201145852,N'AKASH
> DINI',**2.800000000000000e+004**,**2.800000000000000e+004**,**0.000000000000000e+000**,NULL,0,0,306076,331912,{ts
> '2021-02-20 13:08:07.720'},0.000000000000000e+000,145,{ts '2021-02-20
> 13:08:07.720'},**2.500000000000000e+001**,104,{ts '2021-02-20
> 13:08:07.720'},0.000000000000000e+000,2,0.000000000000000e+000,NULL,'MM730',NULL,
> 0.000000000000000e+000,0.000000000000000e+000,0.000000000000000e+000,0.000000000000000e+000,NULL,NULL,NULL,'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,246,NULL,0,0.000000000000000e+000,0.000000000000000e+000,NULL,NULL,48,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,'TUE',0,NULL,0.000000000000000e+000,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,{ts
> '2021-02-20
> 13:08:07.720'},'MM166',NULL,NULL,0,NULL,'W',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N'N',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

Not sure why INSERT Statement float values are coming in the displayed format instead of the normal values. Distributor to Subscriber seems to be failing due to this reason.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did somebody change the table schema in the Publisher after replication was set up?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the code and paste on SSMS that  you can take the row numbers and count like that will give you why you have the error.
Therefore,I think you should use on SSMS.Right click on Table of you want to Insert,script table as->Insert Into-> New Query Editor Window

Also,You must convert your datatype of code to sql datatype in your programming language to exchange data with sql,if you use staticly typed language.

InsertColumnCount ValueCount
93                91

```
  insert into [dbo].[Table] ( 
    [id],
    [Client_No],
    [Loan_No],
    [Client_Name],
    [Loan_Amt],
    [Loan_Balance],
    [Loan_Int_Paid],
    [Loan_lsinst],
    [PartAmt],
    [InstNoPaid],
    [CentreId],
    [GroupId],
    [Loan_Dt],
    [finChrg],
    [Loan_Stat],
    [FirstInstDt],
    [Loan_Int],
    [Loan_Prd],
    [Loan_DueDt],
    [Loan_Inst],
    [Loan_Typ],
    [IRR],
    [FlatRate],
    [ROCode],
    [ROCodeOrg],
    [Loan_pen],
    [Loan_penpaid],
    [loan_Oc],
    [Loan_Ocpaid],
    [Loan_legal],
    [WOff],
    [WOffDt],
    [Reschedule],
    [Loan_Suggest],
    [Loan_Leg_Rem],
    [loan_woff_rem],
    [loan_sector],
    [loan_use],
    [Loan_ClDt],
    [Brn_Code],
    [Remarks],
    [I nsureAmt],
    [ProcessFee],
    [sTax],
    [trn_autNo],
    [LastPaidOn],
    [Loan_Cat],
    [Cycle],
    [invoiceNo],
    [BuyOutDt],
    [BuyOutBnk],
    [BuyOutFlg],
    [ResponseDt],
    [EndLoanUtil],
    [Util_Empno],
    [InsurComp],
    [CoolDys],
    [Collday],
    [CollWeek],
    [NetDisbFlg],
    [ML_ClAmt],
    [LastPaidAmt],
    [WoffBO],
    [WoffBODt],
    [LastEMI],
    [DisbBank],
    [NextDueDt],
    [ArrearNos],
    [DisbTyp],
    [GL_Fdgl],
    [GAN],
    [Bank_Id],
    [Nominee_Id],
    [IsAndroid],
    [Created_On],
    [Created_By],
    [Updated_On],
    [Updated_By],
    [Doc_Download],
    [Lot_Time],
    [CollMode],
    [Ref_LoanNo],
    [Sanction_dt],
    [GenInsu],
    [NatCatInsr],
    [MasterLoanUtil],
    [NachStatus],
    [NatCatInsrFlg],
    [SoftCopyStatus],
    [PennyDrop],
    [EximId],
    [Mort_Int],
    [InterestPaidUpto],
    [MortInsAmt]) 
    values ( 
    6494935,
    1002460000002934,
    1102460201145852,
    N'AKASH DINI',
    2.800000000000000e+004,
    2.800000000000000e+004,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    NULL,
    0,
    0,
    306076,
    331912,
    {ts '2021-02-20 13:08:07.720'},
    0.000000000000000e+000,145,
    {ts '2021-02-20 13:08:07.720'},
    2.500000000000000e+001,104,
    {ts '2021-02-20 13:08:07.720'},
    0.000000000000000e+000
    ,2
    ,0.000000000000000e+000,
    NULL,
    'MM730',
    NULL,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'N',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    246,
    NULL,
    0,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    48,
    1,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    'TUE',
    0,
    NULL,
    0.000000000000000e+000,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    1,
    {ts '2021-02-20 13:08:07.720'},
    'MM166',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    'W',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    N'N',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL)
    
    select (95-2) as InsertColumnCount,(188-97) as ValueCount
```

Comment: Thanks Omer for your patience. This query is actually coming from the Publisher for replication onto the Subscriber. The query works perfect in SSMS when I remove the first column(which is an IDENTITY column). I have NOT FOR REPLICATION set to TRUE on the publisher database for this specific table since I wanted the same IDENTITY value on the Subscriber. Am I doing it right ?